# Selenium with Python - Finding an element after a selected one

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find an link text but after a specific image but i can't find a way to do it properly with Selenium . My code is just down bellow

```
 

    browser.get(URL)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="Images"]')
    browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Bla").click()
```

I need to start my partial link text selection after the specific xpath. Do you know an easy way to do this ?

This is the architecture of the html page (it's not public and it's just a portion of it ):

```
<tr style="background-color:#E5E5E5;font-size:9pt;">
            <td align="center" style="width:70px;">05/03/2018</td><td align="center" style="width:40px;">
                    <img id="1" src="Images" style="border-width:0px;">
                </td><td>
                    <span id="2"></span>
                    <a id="3" href="javascript:OuvreFenetre(3683826,241258727)">Blabla</a>
                    <span id="4"></span>
                </td>
        </tr>
```

I locate the img with the scr="Images" but i need to select the hyperlinks just after that (call here "Blabla").

Comment: You are not doing anything for this web element `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="src"]')` and when you do this `browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("words").click()` what is the error ? Can you share HTML also

Comment: I hide  the source image but those two requests works fine alone but i just need to start my link selection after the first requests ;)  My problem is that the find element function starts from  scratch and not after the selected element find from the xpath

Comment: But this line is `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="src"]')` is useless until you perform any operation on that

Comment: my purpose with this line is to "block" the browser and start my second requests after the end of the first one . I just don't know how to make selenium understand that "ok you find the element by xpath but what it the next element after this one  (with his an hyperlinks) which contains the worlds i specified . It is clear for you ?

Comment: If anchor tag is child of image tag the probably you can do like this : `//img[@src="src"]/a[contains(@href, '')]`

Comment: I dont' think it's a child but the hyperlink i want  is  near it

Comment: It's a `following-sibling` not child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this :

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="src"]').is_displayed():
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("words").click()
```

or if you want to introduce `WebDriverWait`, use it like below : (more reliable solution)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
if wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "your xpath here"))).is_displayed():
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("words").click()
```

or If anchor tag is child of image tag the probably you can do like this : `//img[@src="src"]/a[contains(@href, ' href here')]`

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

You can select anchro tag based on **Image src** like below :

```
//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/following-sibling::a
```

so instead of these two lines :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="Images"]')
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Bla").click()
```

You can use the above xpath like this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/following-sibling::a").click()
```

or

```
//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/following-sibling::a[contains(@href, 'javascript')]
```

**Update 2:**

Use the below xpath :

```
//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/../following-sibling::td/a
```

Comment: I think I would need to see your HTML structure, Can you share ? or If URL is public then let me know, I can take a look

Comment: I edit my post you can view a part of the html structure ;)

Comment: I try with only the img part of the code : it works fine but the following-sibling part don't works

Comment: What is the exception that you got ? and are you using the `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/following-sibling::a").click()` line ?

Comment: Unable to locate element and yes i use this line !

Comment: Press F12 and then go to element section and press  `CTRL + F ` and in search bar write this `//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/following-sibling::a` and see how many entries are there ?

Comment: //img[contains(@src, 'Images)] works fine : i found 1 entry but when i add /following-sibling::a it's found nothing

Comment: and when you do `//a[@id='3']` , do you see anchor tag getting highlighted

Comment: then try to use `browser.find_element_by_id("//a[@id='3']").click()` and see if that works

Comment: I will definitly works but my purpose here is to creat a process over 60000 URL and the id of what i try to select is different over all URL. That why I try to find something which doesn't change over the URL which is the icon just before the hyperkinks i want ;)

Comment: for all those 6K URL, do you think Image src won't change ? I don't think so. The HTML that you have shared a is a following-sibling, Are you sure that it is the second element from the img ? Is it not nested  ?

Comment: Yes the scr doesn't change : it's just a file icon very general . But the fact is that after this icon i generaly have an hyperlink that i want to open ;)

the architecture is :
 on a tr element (which is a line) we have 3 td  elements :
          - td elements N°1 : i don' care
          - td elements N°2:  the img
          - td elements N°3 : the hyperlinks i want

The architecture is just the same as my post !

Comment: wait a min. I thought there were only 2 `td` , no there are 3 tds, I will update my answer

Comment: In same element section search this `//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/../following-sibling::a` and see the link is getting highlighted. I have updated my answer in Update 2 section

Comment: Nope can't find it !

Comment: `//img[contains(@src, 'Images')]/../following-sibling::td/a` try this